# Rectangle where $E$ is a point on side and finding length of angle bisector of $\angle BED$

Tags: geometry

> In rectangle $ABCD$ with $AB=5$ and $BC=4,$ point $E$ is on side $CD$ such that $AE$ bisects $\angle BED.$ Compute the length of $AE.$

I graphed it in Geogebra and saw [image]

this. It seems $DE=2$ and $EC=3,$ but so I can just compute the lengths with coordinates, but how would I do this without using geogebra? I know $\sin \angle AED = \tfrac{4}{AE},$ but I'm not sure how to find the angle of $\angle AED.$ Furthermore I know the diagonal of the rectangle is $\sqrt{41}.$ I'm not sure how to proceed. I wonder if there is a nice synthetic solution I'm missing. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your angles labeled $\beta$ and $\gamma$ it follows $BAE$ is an isosceles triangle. Therefore $BE=5.$ Plotting this on the coordinate plane with $B=(5,4)$ and $E=(x,0),$ then we have $$\sqrt{(5-x)^2+4^2}=5,$$ and solving we have $x=2,8,$ but clearly $8$ is impossible since the side length is $5,$ so now that $E=(2,0)$ it is easy to find the length $AE.$

Comment: Thanks! So then $AE=\sqrt{2^2+4^2}=2\sqrt{5}?$

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative (less elegant) approach:

$\underline{\text{Tools:}}$

- $\displaystyle \tan (r + s) = \frac{\tan(r) + \tan(s)}{1 - [\tan(r)\tan(s)]}.$
- $\displaystyle \tan (r - s) = \frac{\tan(r) - \tan(s)}{1 + [\tan(r)\tan(s)]}.$
- $\tan(180^\circ) = 0.$
- From the diagram:
  $90^\circ < 2\alpha < 180^\circ \implies 45^\circ < \alpha < 90^\circ \implies \tan(\alpha) > 1.$

---

$\underline{\text{Plan of Attack}}$

- $\overline{BE} + \overline{EC} = 5.$
- Express each of $~\overline{BE}, \overline{EC}~$ in terms of $~\tan(\alpha).$
- Solve for $~\tan(\alpha)$.
- Solve for $\overline{BE}.$

Demonstrating that $~\overline{BE} = 2~$ will dovetail into the answer of Bongocat.

---

$\displaystyle \frac{4}{\overline{BE}} = \tan(\alpha) \implies \frac{4}{\tan(\alpha)} = \overline{BE}.$

$\displaystyle \frac{4}{\overline{EC}} = \tan(180^\circ - 2\alpha) \implies \frac{4}{\tan(180^\circ - 2\alpha)} = \overline{EC}.$

$\displaystyle \tan(180^\circ - 2\alpha) = \frac{\tan(180^\circ) - \tan(2\alpha)}{1 + [\tan(180^\circ)\tan(2\alpha)]}
 = - \tan(2\alpha) = \frac{- 2\tan(\alpha)}{1 - \tan^2(\alpha)}.$

---

Therefore,

$\displaystyle 5 = \frac{4}{\tan(\alpha)} + \frac{4}{\tan(180^\circ - 2\alpha)} 
= \frac{4}{\tan(\alpha)} + \frac{4[1 - \tan^2(\alpha)]}{- 2\tan(\alpha)} \implies $

$\displaystyle 5 = \frac{8}{2\tan(\alpha)} + \frac{4[\tan^2(\alpha) - 1]}{2\tan(\alpha)} = 
\frac{4 + 4\tan^2(\alpha)}{2\tan(\alpha)}.$

Letting $~u = \tan\alpha~$ implies that 
$10u = 4 + 4u^2 \implies 2u^2 - 5u + 2 = 0 \implies $

$\displaystyle u = \frac{1}{4}\left[5 \pm \sqrt{25 - 16}\right] \implies \tan(\alpha) = u \in \left\{2, \frac{1}{2}\right\}.$

Since $~\tan(u) > 1,~$ this implies that 
$\tan(u) = 2 \implies \overline{BE} = 2.$

**Edit**
As the answer of Bongocat indicates, an alternative approach to *rejecting* $~\displaystyle \tan(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}~$ is that it would imply that $~\overline{BE} = 8 > 5.$

Answer (score 0):

Let drop altitude $AF$ to $BE$. Then triangles $ADE$ and $AFE$ are congruent right triangles. Then $AF$ is 4. Using Pythagoras theorem one can find $BF=\sqrt{AB^2-AF^2}=3$. Angles $BAE$ and $AEB$ are congruent, then triangle $ABE$ is isosceles with $BE=AB=5$, then $DF=EF=BE-BF=2$, then $\alpha=\arctan\frac{AD}{DF}=\arctan 2\approx 63.435^\circ$.